# Building a docker image via the VSCode extention

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image by right clicking the docker file and selecting the "Build image" option (using the VSCode official Docker extension). When I do so, nothing happens (no image appears at the image section at the docker tab). Does that mean that the build failed? If so, how do I get an indication as to when it happens and how do I see the logged errors? Currently I have no feedback on the operation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. VSCode simply typed the command into the Command Platte and I just didn't press "enter" to send it. When I do, a terminal opens with full details. The command didn't even run.